# Check if docker remote registry is running and can accept image

Tags: docker, docker-registry

It is possible to check if docker remote registry is online and can accept image push?

I am having issues when I am logged in remote registry but i am unable to push image sometimes. Therefore I would like to obtain the info earlier then after I create image with docker build.

Comment: What kind of error do you have when you are unable to push the images?

Comment: 4f90d06b194f: Retrying in 3 seconds
2231
e8781a8efbd2: Retrying in 3 seconds
2232
4773582e8d54: Retrying in 2 seconds
2233
42c0599f0b36: Retrying in 2 seconds
2234
534ae32afe5e: Retrying in 2 seconds
2235
4f90d06b194f: Retrying in 2 seconds
2236
e8781a8efbd2: Retrying in 2 seconds
2237
4773582e8d54: Retrying in 1 second
2238
42c0599f0b36: Retrying in 1 second
2239
534ae32afe5e: Retrying in 1 second
2240
4f90d06b194f: Retrying in 1 second
2241
e8781a8efbd2: Retrying in 1 second
2242
received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error